# SwiftUI Preview not rendering

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-previews, xcode-previews

I am trying to use SwiftUI in my project where I was using UIKit only, until now. The problem is that Preview in Xcode is not working even for very simple View with Text("Hello World"). Code is correct and project is possible to build and run. Even when I try to select real device (real iPhone) I can see Preview in my device. But Preview in simulator is not working. Can someone help me with this? I am attaching [diagnostic from Xcode](https://jmp.sh/s/0aL7Midte1zAsqWUCJa2). Thanks for help

[image]

**Edit:** I removed most of the packages used via SPM and remove almost all custom code from AppDelegate but it didn't helped. But It made [diagnostic from Xcode Preview](https://jmp.sh/zdgw0bB7) much shorter. So maybe it could help more now.

Comment: Can you show the preview screen on XCode?

Comment: @son No, I can't.

Comment: I mean, what is the error XCode shows up?

Comment: I added Image showing error in Xcode. When I try to get more info in Diagnostic popup I get error message I attached before.

Comment: Can you try to run this command line? `xcrun simctl --set previews delete all`

Comment: I tried that before and I tried it again now (while Xcode was not running) but it didn't helped. In other projects Xcode Preview for SwiftUI is working but not in this one.

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with FBProcess something isn’t getting setup that should. Canvas does not start from the entry point to your View so any setup being done in the AppDelegate/SceneDelegate/Root isn’t completed. I usually mock 3rd parties when in preview/debug if you have proper architecture it shouldn’t take much to just not use Facebook when running on Canvas

Comment: I tried to remove all code (all imports and all init methods etc.) from AppDelegate to be like new one. But it didn't help. Not using SceneDelegate. Is it possible to find some flow and what code is building during preview progress? Or do you have any more idea where problem could be?

Comment: Remove the Facebook package see if it works. If it does then you have narrowed down the issue. If it doesn’t check the error again and see if it references another package.

Comment: I removed facebook package and other packages that could be easily removed but It didn't help. I updated question with new diagnostic message. There are few packages removing that I can't easily remove.

Comment: I get the impression that it is still something with the packages. Try updating them or even rolling them back. I don’t have anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance. It took me a while, but I finally figured out where the issue was. I had to reduce the entire project to its bare minimum, and only then did I discover that the problem likely lay somewhere in the configuration. The issue was that 'arm64' was listed under Excluded Architectures. Since I inherited the project, I was unaware of this setting. It's a pity that Xcode doesn't indicate such reasons, as it would simplify the process of identifying problems.